# How to log in as a user in p4

Tags: version-control, perforce

I have an issue where users are trying to log in to their Perforce account using `p4` command line (not `p4v` visual client), but it seems to start at a default account without permissions. When they try to logout with

> `p4 logout`

the users get following error

> "Access for user "foo" has not been enabled by 'p4 protect'".

What is the standard way of logging out and logging in via `p4` command line?

Answer (score 19):

For ease of use, make sure to set your username via the P4USER environment variable first, then use `p4 login` and `p4 logout` You could also use `p4 -u <username> login`

Comment: This was my first guess.  Although "p4 login <username>" does not work, p4 -u <username> login" APPEARS to work.  However, if I use "p4 info" afterward, it is still logged in as user name "foo".

Comment: you have to use `p4 -u <username> info` That was why I said for ease of use set the P4USER environment variable

Comment: Indeed, you can be logged in as multiple users simultaneously, and issue each command using a different identity, via -u or P4USER, as George says. Another technique is to set up a P4CONFIG file.

Answer (score 17):

The following command fixed my problems. It is definitely what a flat described above but I am spelling it out for those who get confused with the extra comments and information.

For Windows and Mac OS X user

> `p4 set P4USER=<username>`

For Linux users as there is no registry to store values of environment variables

> `export P4USER=<username>`

you can then use

> `p4 info`

to verify that the new username is being used.

Answer (score 5):

For me `p4 -u username login` worked, but when I tried to run other commands like `p4 sync` it was using the local username, so I used `p4 -u username sync`, it appears to work. I think every `p4` command should start with `p4 -u username`

Comment: But why is that? is it impossible to login persistently?

Answer (score 3):

To fix

*"Access for user 'foo' has not been enabled by 'p4 protect'."

Edit the permissions table and give the group that they're in access to read something.

If you're on Unix you can login as an admin account and run:

```
p4 protect
```

This will open the "Protections:" table in a text editor.

Add this at the bottom:

```
read group foo-group * //foo/...
```

(where foo-group is a group that foo is in, and //foo/... is a depot you want foo-group to have read access to)

NOW the user foo should be able to login.